# Upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, but I still have old UI

Tags: 18.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 but the UI did not change at all. For example I don't have the full screen app launcher; it's the same as it was back in 16 and 17. No notification center etc.

Do I need to somehow opt in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you were running Ubuntu 16.04 you were on the **Unity** interface. After upgrading to 18.04 the Unity interface is still there but new interfaces are offered as well. It sounds like you are searching for the **Gnome** Desktop which you can select from the "gear" next to the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button during login:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 Five Desktops.jpg]

You can try all the desktops to see which you like best but keep in mind:

- Many have reported problems using the Wayland window manager which was designed to replace X11 but has not lived up to expectations.
- When I tested 18.04 upgrade of 16.04 clone some of the options resulted in a purple screen with only a movable mouse cursor.