# Desktop design still similar to Ubuntu 16.04 even after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 19.04, desktop-environments

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 then to 19.04, but it still looks like the 16.04 version:
[image]

What should I do to make it look like the 19.04?

Comment: A duplicate 1 year older: [ubuntu 18.04 but I still have old UI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035446/ubuntu-18-04-but-i-still-have-old-ui/1035452#1035452)

Comment: If you upgraded from Unity - a simple logout, and switch to "Ubuntu" will switch to GNOME.  You will have Unity 7 (pre-17.10 default desktop) and GNOME (new default) and it's kept you Unity to avoid change; until you select it at login screen.

Comment: it works thank you so much guys