# Lightdm uninstalled

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, lightdm

[image]I uninstalled lightdm from my pc by mistake and then rebooted my pc now I cannot even log in to install it(it is looped in the login page and the same thing happens in the terminal too)
I entered the shell using single user mode hack but there my wifi interface isn't working I can't connect to my wifi to install lightdm
Edit: I think my bash is broken because no installation is taking place they all return with the error:error encountered while processing bash

Comment: Try logging in with a different desktop manger. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035446/upgraded-to-ubuntu-18-04-but-i-still-have-old-ui/1035452#1035452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least three options here.

---

**Option One: if you are using standard 20.04, you should have GDM installed.**

If this is the case, you can run the following command to select GDM as the display manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

If you need to, you can start GDM by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start gdm
```

---

**Option Two: if you can get to a terminal and you need wifi, you can start your `network-manager` service using the following command:**

```
sudo systemctl start network-manager
```

This should connect you to the internet automatically. You can use `nmcli` commands to check your network status or to connect to a network.

```
nmcli
```

For example, if your network SSID name is "AWESOME" then you would use the following command to connect to the network:

```
sudo nmcli -ask device wifi connect AWESOME password wireless-password
```

and enter the password at the prompt.

Of course, after you connect to the network, you can install `lightdm` using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Then, start lightdm:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

---

**Option Three: you can access a graphical desktop environment without lightdm by running the following command:**

```
startx
```

However, make sure you **do not use `sudo startx`** and **do not run `startx` as root user** as this will cause future permission issues that may prevent your regular user from logging in. Again, **do not run `startx` with `sudo`**.

This should also give you access to wifi and from there, you will be able to install `lightdm`.

When you are done, you can poweroff your computer or reboot from the X session by one of the following commands:

```
sudo poweroff
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I got wifi connection using that command but I cannot install lightdm there is an error saying that they encountered an error while processing bash

Comment: By the way I am doing it all in single user mode and not on tty

Comment: @Deva Sorry I've been away. You can run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install --reinstall bash` first and then see if you get any errors.

Comment: can you message me on reddit I have a bit of a problem messaging on askubuntu I'm u/dnb02

Comment: and yeah I've tried that it isn't working @mchid neither installation nor removal is taking place all the commands return with the error that bash cannot be configured!

Comment: @Deva I don't have a reddit but we can move this to chat room if you'd like. I can ask the moderators to move this to chat if you'd like.

Comment: @Deva However, what I would do in this situation is make a working directory: `mkdir bash` change to the directory: `cd bash` download bash: `apt download bash` and then manually install this using dpkg: `sudo dpkg -i bash*` and then run the following to clean stuff up: `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @Deva Also, I think you should open a separate question for the broken bash problem. I think you might get a better response from the community on this particular question. It is best to keep the scope to one question at a time.

Answer (score 3):

First connect to the wifi using `nmtui`.

Then you should still be able to login into a virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, login with your credentials, then reinstall lightdm with `sudo apt install lightdm`.

If this doesn't work, try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop (if you are using Ubuntu. Otherwise replace with the respective package for different Ubuntu flavours) with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` or reconfiguring packages with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: The OP can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Installation not finishing it says that it has encountered an error while processing bash